# frequency counts with categorical variables

Tags: r, frequency, categorical-data

I have two categorical variables.

Variable A has about 15 levels and Variable B is dummy coded (0,1)

I am looking to get a table with the frequency counts of 1's in Variable B for each of the 15 levels of Variable A.

Comment: You can use `table` i.e. `table(df1[c('A', 'B')])`

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `table` from `base R` after subsetting the columns of interest

```
table(df1[c('A', 'B')])
```